# Typeahead.js / Bloodhound when clicking on suggestion, populates search box with object instead of name

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, typeahead.js, bloodhound

When I start typing the name of a golf course in a search box using Typeahead.js and Bloodhound, the dropdown correctly shows just the name of the golf course.

## Problem

- When I click on `.tt-suggestion`, which contains the course's name, the text that populates the search box is the golf course object instead of obj.name, which is stored in `var courses = []`

### scripts.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
        return function findMatches(q, cb) {
          var matches, substringRegex;

          // an array that will be populated with substring matches
          matches = [];

          // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
          substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

          // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
          // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
          $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
            if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
              matches.push(str);
            }
          });

          cb(matches);
        };
    };

    var courses = [
        {% for content in COPY.courses%}
        { 
            "name": "{{content.name}}",
            "url": "/courses/{{content.slug}}",
        },
        {% endfor %}
    ];

    var source = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        local: courses
    });

    source.initialize();

    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'courses',
        source: source.ttAdapter(),
        templates: {
            empty: [
                '<div class="empty-message">We could not find any golf courses with that name</div>'
            ],
            suggestion: function(data) {
                return '<div><a href="' + course.url + '">' + course.name + '</a></div>';
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

### index.html

```
<div class="search search--home">
    <label class="search__label">Search all courses</label>
    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input class="typeahead" type="search" name="" placeholder="Search all golf courses">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are a seeing a JSON object instead of the specific value you want, you can use `displayKey: 'name'` for instance to show just that value.

The solution comes from this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560108/typeahead-v0-10-2-bloodhound-working-with-nested-json-objects)